# How to query table col for multiple values

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I've done a horrible thing...

I've got a table that contains account balances. It has attributes for the account_id, the amount, and the month_end date.  I wanted to query that table for the balances for the last twelve months.  But there's gotta be a better way to do it than this.

```
scope :recent_balances, lambda { { :conditions => 
  ["month_end = ? OR month_end = ? OR month_end = ? OR month_end = ? OR month_end = ? OR month_end = ? OR month_end = ? OR month_end = ? OR month_end = ? OR month_end = ? OR month_end = ? OR month_end = ?", 
  last_month_end.to_s, 
  (last_month_end-1.month).end_of_month.to_s,
  (last_month_end-2.month).end_of_month.to_s,
  (last_month_end-3.month).end_of_month.to_s,
  (last_month_end-4.month).end_of_month.to_s,
  (last_month_end-5.month).end_of_month.to_s,
  (last_month_end-6.month).end_of_month.to_s,
  (last_month_end-7.month).end_of_month.to_s,
  (last_month_end-8.month).end_of_month.to_s,
  (last_month_end-9.month).end_of_month.to_s,
  (last_month_end-10.month).end_of_month.to_s,
  (last_month_end-11.month).end_of_month.to_s ] } }

private

def self.last_month_end
  last_month_end ||= (Date.today - 1.month).end_of_month
end
```

My questions are:

1. What's the smart way to do this query?  (There's no way it's what I just came up with.)
2. How can I modify this query to make it more flexible?  I'd like to be able to pass in a particular number of months to the query (e.g. query for six months of balances or for 24 months of balances)

Comment: Do you want "last year" to be from 1/1 to 12/31 or from a year-ago-today to today? In either case, databases support searching between ranges of dates, using something like "date >= startdate and date <= enddate".

Comment: I'm looking to do a query from the most recent month end to a year-ago, not necessarily a Jan-Dec calendar year.  I hadn't thought about this strategy: "date >= startdate and date <= enddate", but it seems like an elegant solution.

Comment: I'm not sure it's elegant, but it's how I've always seen it done.

Comment: Is `month_end` a date field or a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
months = (1..11).map { |m| last_month_end.advance(months: 0 - m) }

where("month_end IN (?)", months)
```

Or something like that.  That would be a more readable and maintainable way of doing what you did above.  As someone else said, you can check if a date is in between a start and an end date in SQL.

```
where("date >= ? AND date <= ?", start_date, end_date)
```

or (better yet)

```
where("date BETWEEN ? AND ?", start_date, end_date)
```

Comment: ActiveRecord finders supports an even more compact `IN` form: `where(month_end: months)`.